# Is it possible to develop sharepoint visual web parts on Windows 7?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I'm trying to develop webparts in my windows 7 box. However, for visual web parts, you need to have Sharepoint server installed locally. Tried to install Sharepoint foundation but it said that the OS is not supported. I guess the answer is going to be no, but is it possible to setup my windows 7 box so I can make this happen? if yes, how? By the way, it is a windows 7 enterprise 64 bits, with 4GB RAM and 300GB of available hard disk. I just don't want to install Win2008 to make it happen. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to install SharePoint 2010 on Windows 7, but you need to extract the install file and modify a config file. This article should help you out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx

I would also consider to add some RAM to that machine, because 4GB is very tight for SharePoint 2010. Your OS will use some, your Visual Studio will use some, perhaps some Office applications (Outlook)...

My preference for development is a local virtual machine. That way, the SharePoint won't consume any resources when you're not developing.

Comment: Look at SP2010 service controller for an easy way to turn on/off all SharePoint services - http://sharepointserviceman.codeplex.com/